# Pandas add calculated row to bottom of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a small sample of a dataframe I have, and I want to add a calculated row to the bottom of it:

```
sch     q1     q2     q3
acc     Yes    Yes    No
acc     Yes    No     No
acc     Yes    No     No
acc     Yes    Yes    Yes
```

I want to add a row at the bottom that will give me the percentage of values that are 'Yes' for each column, so that it would look like below.

```
sch     q1     q2     q3
acc     Yes    Yes    No
acc     Yes    No     No
acc     Yes    No     No
acc     Yes    Yes    Yes
acc     1.00   0.5    0.25
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your lambda and raise a pure pandas solution:

```
df.append(df.eq('Yes').mean(), ignore_index=True)
```

You don't specify what should happen to the `sch` column, so I ignored it. In my current solution this column will get the value `0`.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the best and simplest solution so far.  For sch, I would like to keep the same value, so that should be 'acc' as well.  How would I include this?  Also, if I group by sch, would I then be able to iterate over the groups to add this row to the bottom of each group?

Comment: Since you want to apply the append grouped by `sch`, I would follow the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082412/append-rows-to-a-pandas-groupby-object). Basically, you group your dataframe, write the 'yes'-count to a new dataframe, then ungroup the original dataframe to append the 'yes'-count-dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

assume the following approach:

```
In [11]: df.loc[len(df)] = ['acc'] + df.filter(regex='^q\d+') \
                                       .eq('Yes').mean().values.tolist()

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   sch   q1   q2    q3
0  acc  Yes  Yes    No
1  acc  Yes   No    No
2  acc  Yes   No    No
3  acc  Yes  Yes   Yes
4  acc    1  0.5  0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.append(df.apply(lambda x: len(x[x=='Yes'])/len(x)),ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    q1   q2    q3
0  Yes  Yes    No
1  Yes   No    No
2  Yes   No    No
3  Yes  Yes   Yes
4    1  0.5  0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `pd.concat`, `mean`, `to_frame`, and T for transpose.

```
pd.concat([df,df.replace({'Yes':True,'No':False}).mean().to_frame().T.assign(sch='acc')])
```

Output:

```
    q1   q2    q3  sch
0  Yes  Yes    No  acc
1  Yes   No    No  acc
2  Yes   No    No  acc
3  Yes  Yes   Yes  acc
0    1  0.5  0.25  acc
```