# Group by with aggregation function as new field in pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

If I do the following group by on a mysql table

```
SELECT col1, count(col2) * count(distinct(col3)) as agg_col
FROM my_table
GROUP BY col1
```

what I get is a table with three columns

```
col1 col2 agg_col
```

How can I do the same on a pandas dataframe?

Suppose I have a Dataframe that has three columns col1 col2 and col3. Group by operation

```
grouped = my_df.groupby('col1')
```

will returned the data grouped by col1

Also

```
agg_col_series = grouped.col2.size() * grouped.col3.nunique()
```

will return the aggregated column equivalent to the one on the sql query. But how can I add this on the grouped dataframe?

Comment: Might this help you manipulating groupby objects?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe

Comment: Also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082412/append-rows-to-a-pandas-groupby-object

Comment: Are you sure your SQL produces three columns? IMO `col2` is missing in the SELECT and in the GROUP BY clauses...

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible data set and desired data set?

Comment: Agreed with @MaxU, your SQL should only output 2 columns as you multiply two aggregates in `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd need to see your data to be sure, but I think you need to simply reset the index of your `agg_col_series`:

```
agg_col_series.reset_index(name='agg_col')
```

Full example with dummy data:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

col1 = [random.randint(1,5) for x in range(1,1000)]
col2 = [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(1,1000)]
col3 = [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(1,1000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'col1': col1,
        'col2': col2,
        'col3': col3,
    })

grouped = df.groupby('col1')
agg_col_series = grouped.col2.size() * grouped.col3.nunique()

print agg_col_series.reset_index(name='agg_col')

index   col1  agg_col
0       1    15566
1       2    20056
2       3    17313
3       4    17304
4       5    16380
```

Comment: Thank you  Nick!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `groupby` with a lambda function that uses `size` and `nunique`
then `rename` the series to 'agg_col' and `reset_index` to get a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(443)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],50),
                   'Col2':np.random.randint(1000,9999,50),
                   'Col3':np.random.choice(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],50)})

df_out = df.groupby('Col1').apply(lambda x: x.Col2.size * x.Col3.nunique()).rename('agg_col').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Col1  agg_col
0    A      120
1    B       96
2    C      190
```

Comment: Thnaks both of you. The only reason I am choosing @nick-braunagel answer is because he came first and because he has lower reputation in order to increase it :)

Comment: @apostolos. Great!   Glad it worked for you.   Thanks for the upvote.