# How to append a row with specific characteristics to the end of a group?

Tags: python, pandas, append, row

I want to append a row at the end of a dataframe that can be grouped by a variable. 
My dataframe looks like this:

```
|ID | Name1 | Name2 | PointA | PointB | Var1 | Var2 | 
| 1 | AAA   | zzz   | ABC    | BCD    |  1   |  5   | 
| 1 | AAA   | zzz   | BCD    | CDE    |  2   |  5   | 
| 1 | AAA   | zzz   | CDE    | DEF    |  3   |  5   | 
| 2 | BBB   | yyy   | STU    | TUV    |  1   |  6   | 
| 2 | BBB   | yyy   | TUV    | UVW    |  2   |  6   | 
| 2 | BBB   | yyy   | UVW    | VWX    |  3   |  6   | 
| 2 | BBB   | yyy   | VWX    | WXY    |  4   |  6   |
```

And what I want is to add a row at the end of each category as defined by `ID`:

```
|ID | Name1 | Name2 | PointA | PointB | Var1 | Var2 | 
| 1 | AAA   | zzz   | ABC    | BCD    |  1   |  5   | 
| 1 | AAA   | zzz   | BCD    | CDE    |  2   |  5   | 
| 1 | AAA   | zzz   | CDE    | DEF    |  3   |  5   | 
| 1 | AAA   | zzz   | DEF    | ---    |  4   |  0   | 
| 2 | BBB   | yyy   | STU    | TUV    |  1   |  6   | 
| 2 | BBB   | yyy   | TUV    | UVW    |  2   |  6   | 
| 2 | BBB   | yyy   | UVW    | VWX    |  3   |  6   | 
| 2 | BBB   | yyy   | VWX    | WXY    |  4   |  6   | 
| 2 | BBB   | yyy   | WXY    | ---    |  5   |  0   |
```

I have tried: (my original df is called `operacionales`)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = operacionales.columns)
val = range(1, 22223)
for x in val:
    test = operacionales.loc[operacionales['ID'] == x]
    li = [test.ID.iloc[0], test.Name1.iloc[0], test.Name2.iloc[0],
test.PointB.iloc[-1], '-', test.Var1.max() + 1, 0]
    t = pd.DataFrame(li).T
    t.columns = test.columns
    test2 = test.append(t)
    df = df.append(test2)
```

but I got a "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"
 I tried the same but with the index `[-1]` instead of `[0]` in the code and the result is the same.

As you can see the row I want to add is is just the same as the other rows of the group, except for: 
1. `PointA` (which I want to be the last value of the `PointB` variable), 
2. `PointB` (which I want to set to a '---'), 
3. `Var1` (which I want to be +1 of the last value in the group), and 
4. `Point2` (which I want to set to 0).

I found this ([append rows to a Pandas groupby object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082412/append-rows-to-a-pandas-groupby-object)) but it doesn't really helped me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groupby / apply:

```py
def append_column_to_group(group):
    result = group
    result = result.append({'ID': 1,
                            'Name1': group.iloc[0].Name1,
                            'Name2': group.iloc[0].Name2,
                            'PointA': group.iloc[-1].PointB,
                            'PointB': '---',
                            'Var1': group.iloc[-1].Var1 + 1,
                            'Var2': 0}, ignore_index=True)
    return result
df.groupby('Name1').apply(append_column_to_group)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def update_method(series):
    last_row = series.iloc[-1]
    new_row = last_row
    new_row['PointA'] = last_row['PointA']
    new_row['PointB'] = '---'
    new_row['Var1'] = last_row['Var1']+1
    series = series.append(new_row)
    return series
new_df = df.groupby('Name1').apply(update_method)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
appenddf=df.groupby('ID').tail(1)
appenddf=appenddf.drop('PointA',1).rename(columns={'PointB':'PointA'}).assign(Var1=appenddf.Var1+1)
df=pd.concat([df,appenddf],sort=True).sort_index()
df
Out[232]: 
   ID Name1 Name2 PointA PointB  Var1  Var2
0   1   AAA   zzz    ABC    BCD     1     5
1   1   AAA   zzz    BCD    CDE     2     5
2   1   AAA   zzz    CDE    DEF     3     5
2   1   AAA   zzz    DEF    NaN     4     5
3   2   BBB   yyy    STU    TUV     1     6
4   2   BBB   yyy    TUV    UVW     2     6
5   2   BBB   yyy    UVW    VWX     3     6
6   2   BBB   yyy    VWX    WXY     4     6
6   2   BBB   yyy    WXY    NaN     5     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
t = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).last() 
t[['PointA', 'PointB', 'Var1', 'Var2']] = np.column_stack([t.PointB, ['---']*2, t.Var1+1, [0]*2])
pd.concat([df, t], ignore_index=True).sort_values('ID')

Out[121]:
   ID Name1 Name2 PointA PointB  Var1  Var2
0   1   AAA   zzz    ABC    BCD     1     5
1   1   AAA   zzz    BCD    CDE     2     5
2   1   AAA   zzz    CDE    DEF     3     5
7   1   AAA   zzz    DEF    ---     4     0
3   2   BBB   yyy    STU    TUV     1     6
4   2   BBB   yyy    TUV    UVW     2     6
5   2   BBB   yyy    UVW    VWX     3     6
6   2   BBB   yyy    VWX    WXY     4     6
8   2   BBB   yyy    WXY    ---     5     0
```